# Loop Controler in jmeter with multiple users

Tags: jmeter

I have scenario,the steps mentioned below:-

Step#1. Login to the application 
Step#2. Upload an excel file (It will display all the uploaded records in the page)
 Step#3. Need to click on each record one by one(Assuming that each file has 10 records)

NOTE:- Need to exceute the above steps with multiple users.

I have created a test plan as below:-

1.Login 
2.Upload file(With CSV config which has upload file info) 
3.Loop control(iterates 10 times,with CSV config which has record details,for clicking)
 3.1.click on record

The problem am facing is,when i execute the above testplan with 10 users ,at any point of time only 1 user is exceuting in the loop control.
 Is there anything am missing here..

regards.

Answer (score 1):

Could you be more clear in regards to expected results and share your CSV Data Set Config details? I'm particularly interested in `Sharing Mode` setting.

As per [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) guide

> It is worth mentioning that every CSV Data Set Config is visible to all Thread Groups by default. If you need to use separate CSV Data Set Config for every Thread, you create a number of data files that you need and in every CSV Data Set Config set “Sharing mode” to “Current Thread”

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, 

Expected:-I Need to exceute the test plan with multiple users,where each userexecutes with UNIQUE data for 10 times. (for processing 10 records) 

I need each user to iterate through UNIQUE data from CSV  config in LOOP CONTROLLER. 
Eg:- 
user1--->user1loop1 
             user1loop2 
             ....... 
             ....... 
             user1loop10 

user2--->user2loop1 
             user2loop2 
             ....... 
             user2loop10

Comment: i have used 2 config files,on with in the loop controller,and other outside loop controller,both csv config 'sharingmode' set to 'ALL THREDS'.Is there any mechansim to control the 'CSV Config elemsnt' in Loop controller so that each user can use only alloted 10 set of values and no other user should use the other user's alloted set of data

Comment: If you need unique data for each of 10 users you need 10 separate CSV files like user1.csv, user2.csv, etc.  And add a variable to your CSV Data Set Config which will reflect current user as user/${__threadNum}.csv so it would be user1.csv for thread 1, user2.csv for thread 2, etc. See https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum for more details.

Comment: Hi Dimitri,i got it and provided the 'Filename' dynamically using \test${__threadNum}.txt,But when i am running the test plan for multiple iteartions,How to dynamically supply the CSV file?